# GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes inside Local Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, driver

So  I've got problem with this function :

```
GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS,&NumPathArrayElements,&NumModeInfoArrayElements);
```

When I run program as standard exe file everything running perfect and both variables `NumPathArrayElements`, `NumModeInfoArrayElements` are greater then 0.

If I run it as local windows service, both are 0.
Return value of function is 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS).

This function is part of  Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM). Is there any problem with access right or ? What do you think ?

Any advice? Thank you. :)

Comment: What would you expect to happen here. You are in a service, in session 0, non-interactive session. Why would you expect to know anything about displays?

Comment: well I need windows service that will search for specific external monitor. Then I need to check monitor position and also relocate it.

Comment: Not going to happen. The service runs in a non-interactive session. You need to execute the code in a specific interactive session. For a specific desktop in a specific window station. Service is the wrong place for your code.

Comment: thank you ;) We will have service that will check if our exe running ...